# Are there wavefunctions that don't get more localized as we go backwards in time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality

Gaussian wave packets spread as the time passes, which means that as we go backwards in time they get more localized. Therefore, Gaussian wave packets introduce less uncertainty in the position as the we go backwards in time.

Are there wave functions (not necessarily Gaussian) in Nature that don't behave like this, i.e that don't get localized as we go backwards in time? If so, I think this would mean that the uncertainty they introduce in position doesn't necessarily increase with time (or decrease as we go backwards in time) as it does in the case of a typical Gaussian wave packet.

Comment: Coherent states have constant spread.

Comment: From what source did you get the impression that wavefunctions spread out over time?

Comment: Are you asking about classical waves?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Do coherent states naturally exist in the nature (without a need to somehow produce them)?

Comment: @LewisMiller I am talking about wavefuntions in quantum mechanics.

Comment: QM is time reversible.

Comment: @Ali From  https://www.rp-photonics.com/coherent_states.html:  “The output of a single-frequency laser well above threshold can approach a coherent state, if the long-term phase drift (related to the Schawlow–Townes linewidth) is disregarded.”

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I was wondering if such states can be found in the nature without the need for producing them. The output of a laser is not something natural.

Comment: @Ali where is the boundary between natural and not natural then?  Is the $n$ excited state of a quantum harmonic oscillator natural?

Comment: @Keith You mean the gaussian wavepacket can also spread as we go backwards in time? So it would be meaningless to say that wavefunction will get localized as we go backwards in time, in both time directions we can only see it spreading. Is that true?

Comment: knzhou explains this [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/280203/85443).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I meant particles which have existed forever, like electrons in atoms, photons, etc. I wanted to know if particles exist wavefunctions of which don't get localized no matter how much we go backwards in time. Coherent states have such wavefunctions, but can a particle in a coherent state have existed since the big bang?

Comment: @Ali.  If you didn't do this in your QM course, do it now. Superpose the ground state of the quantum oscillator on its first excited state. Observe Δx  Δp oscillate in time.